# Magento log out error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have installed Magento community edition 1.7.0.2.

This is working correctly except for when the user clicks the logout button the website diverts to the url `customer/account/logout/` correctly but it stops on this page and shows the below error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function useProductItem() on a non-object in /home/templatename/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php on line 234`

I have not done any work to this PHP file or to the compare product area in general.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache and cleaning the logs?

Comment: I have tried this but still get the same error. I am also getting this error when I try to login via the create account page.